# Doxygen warning when I use `class A : public B<A>`

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I've the folloging header file:

```
#ifndef MYACTOR_HPP_
#define MYACTOR_HPP_

#include "SomeApp/Core/ActorThread.hpp"

namespace SomeApp {
namespace Application {

class MyActor : public Core::ActorThread<MyActor> {
public:

  using MessageToCGFDelegate = Core::Delegate<void(const Comm::MessageToCGF&)>;

public:

  MyActor() = delete;
  MyActor(Aclass comm);
  MyActor(const MyActor&) = delete;
  MyActor(MyActor&&) = delete;
  virtual ~MyActor() = default;

public:

  MyActor& operator=(const MyActor&) = delete;
  MyActor& operator=(MyActor&&) = delete;

private:

  friend Core::ActorThread<MyActor>;

private:

  Aclass m_comm;
};


} // namespace Application
} // namespace SomeApp

#endif // !MYACTOR_HPP_

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DOCUMENTATION                                                             //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/** \addtogroup System
 *  @{
 */

/**
 * @class SomeApp::Application::MyActor
 *
 * @brief Actor containing the communication plugin.
 */

/** @}*/
```

When I run doxygen, I obtain a warning:

```
Parsing file SomeApp/Application/CommActor.hpp:33: error: no uniquely matching class member found for 
    ActorThread< CommActor >
  Possible candidates:
    'SomeApp::Core::ActorThread< Runnable >::ActorThread()' at line 198 of file SomeApp/Core/ActorThread.hpp
    'SomeApp::Core::ActorThread< Runnable >::ActorThread(const ActorThread &)=delete' at line 313 of file SomeApp/Core/ActorThread.hpp
```

I don't know how to get rid of this warning (that blocks the compilation because we thread warnings as errors in our doxygen configuration.)

I'm using doxygen 1.9.5 (actually the latest version).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which settings did you use (output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) as with the default doxygen settings I get only 2 warnings about non documented entities. Please add the information to the question.

Comment: If you provide a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem it is a lot easier for others to help you.